# Haskell types missmatch

Tags: string, haskell, types, match, loading

I want to make a function that takes a string "path" this is the path of a file that has only one line, I want to take this line and check it if it's a proper expression and if it is to build a tree out of this string, here is the code 
`

```
loadExpression :: String -> Tree Char
loadExpression path = do
 contents <- readFile path
 if checkIfProper $ filter (/=' ') contents
    then buildTreeFromString contents
    else EmptyTree
```

`

But It gives me error "Couldn't match type `IO' with`Tree' " . I know the IO string is different from the normal one but isn't `<-` suppost to do just that ? Converting IO string to a normal one. If I call `buildTreeFromString` with a string like `"(1+2)*3"` it works fine, same for the `checkIfProper`.

The whole error is :

```
Couldn't match type `IO' with `Tree'
Expected type: Tree String
  Actual type: IO String
In the return type of a call of `readFile'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: contents <- readFile path
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`readFile` has type `FilePath -> IO String`, so your `do` block is in the `IO` monad. Your entire function therefore returns an `IO (Tree Char)`, not a `Tree Char`, so you need to change your type signature.

EDIT: You can separate the effectual and pure parts of your function, by creating a function to load the tree from an input string. You can then pass the string from `readFile` into this function:

```
readTree :: String -> Tree Char
readTree contents =
 if checkIfProper $ filter (/=' ') contents
    then buildTreeFromString contents
    else EmptyTree
```

`loadExpression` then becomes:

```
loadExpression :: FilePath -> IO (Tree Char)
loadExpression path = do
  contents <- readFile path
  return (readTree contents)
```

or you can use `fmap`:

```
loadExpression = fmap readTree readFile
```

Comment: Can I make a second function that only loads the string from the file and returns a normal one and then use this normal one in this function I made? I am asking this because  I didn't exactly understand what to change, can you give me example? I am really sorry I am very new to Haskell.

Comment: "so your `do` block is in the `IO` monad" seems misleading: the problem is that he *isn't* in the IO monad (since he's claiming to return a `Tree`), but he needs to be (in order to read from a file). Changing the return type gets him into the IO monad, as needed.

Comment: @amalloy - I don't see how that's confusing - the OP _is_ in IO since `readFile` returns an `IO String`. Their explicit type signature says they are not, but they are and need to fix their declaration to match.